# I am having trouble getting minDate and maxDate set using JSON object

Tags: jquery, date

I have tried several solutions found here and I can not seem to get it to work.

I have these values coming in from an ajax call in a JSON object:

```
    r.event_info.bdate //this contains 2014-01-29
    r.event_info.edate //this contains 2014-02-01
```

tried to insert it as a string: minimum became june 30 2019 to july 28 2019

```
    $('#pres_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        minDate: r.event_info.bdate,
        maxDate: r.event_info.edate
    });
```

tried to use Date object: this was close, but the minimum date was 1-28-2014 and the max was the 1-30-2014

```
    $('#pres_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        minDate: new Date(r.event_info.bdate), 
        maxDate: new Date(r.event_info.edate)
    });
```

Comment: Are the dates in JSON format (e.g:"\/Date(1238540400000)\/")?

Comment: You need to lookup the documentation on the javascrip Date object

Comment: No they are formatted as yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the "-" with "," and have your date pick correctly.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RuWrH/1/)

```
var date = "2014-01-29".replace(/\-/g,', ') ;    
var date1 = "2014-02-01".replace(/\-/g,', ') ;

$('#pres_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date(date),
    maxDate: new Date(date1)

});
```

Comment: Pretty neat, you however need to account for the month starting with 0.

Comment: yes i am assuming as per que that date formats are coming same format and correct. (it will works if all date validation done at server side before ajax call.)

Comment: @Neha, I dont understand your answer to i-- 0 problem.. can i insert 01 as a month or not?

Comment: @SmithSmithy thanks, I mean that if date are in correct format this will work.

Comment: @SmithSmithy, I think what Neha means is that your ajax call need to return 2014-00-29 for Jan 29, 2014 and 2014-11-01 for Dec 1, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

The date should come as a Date object, you need to lookup the documentation on that. Here is one of the ways:

```
var bdateArray = r.event_info.bdate.split('-');
var edateArray = r.event_info.edate.split('-');
$('#pres_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    minDate: (new Date()).setFullYear(parseInt(bdateArray[0], 10), parseInt(bdateArray[1], 10) - 1, parseInt(bdateArray[2], 10))
    // same for maxDate
});
```

Comment: it seems like i should be able to do this: minDate: new Date(bdateArray[0],bdateArray[1],bdateArray[2]),
            maxDate: new Date(edateArray[0],edateArray[1],edateArray[2])

Comment: @SmithSmithy, yeah, that seems right with one exception - in javascrpt date month always starts with 0, so parseInt(edateArray[1]) - 1